zkSync Testnet Slow
I've been trying to deploy a smart contract in the zkSync testnet for about 20 minutes and it still says deploying. I was wondering if it is just notoriously slow, deprecated, or if I did something wrong.  Any push in the right direction would be appreciated. Thanks
